How to config nginx to handle server sent events (SSE) correctly?
I am building a spring boot application to handle sever sent events (SSE):
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class SseBroadcaster {

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, SseEmitter> emitters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void addEmitter(String sessionId, SseEmitter emitter) {
        emitters.put(sessionId, emitter);
    }

    public void removeEmitter(String sessionId) {
        emitters.remove(sessionId);
    }

    public void broadcast(String message) {
        for (String s : emitters.keySet()){
            try {
                emitters.get(s).send(SseEmitter.event().name("message").data(message));
                log.info("Message has been sent to " + s);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Failed to send message to " + s, e);
                removeEmitter(s);
            }
        }
    }
}


package com.example.demo;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter;

import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
@Slf4j
public class SseController {

    @Autowired
    private SseBroadcaster sseBroadcaster;

    @GetMapping("/api/contest/sse")
    public SseEmitter connectToSse() {
        String username = "(Unknown)";
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        String sessionId = username + "-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        sseBroadcaster.addEmitter(sessionId, emitter);
        log.info(username + " connected to SSE, session: " + sessionId);
        emitter.onCompletion(() -> {
            sseBroadcaster.removeEmitter(sessionId);
            log.info(username + " disconnected from SSE, session: " + sessionId);
        });
        emitter.onTimeout(() -> {
            sseBroadcaster.removeEmitter(sessionId);
            log.info(username + " disconnected from SSE, session: " + sessionId);
        });
        return emitter;
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/contest/admin/broadcast")
    public void publishBroadcast(String broadcast) {
        sseBroadcaster.broadcast(broadcast);
        log.info("Published a broadcast: " + broadcast);
    }

}


package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}


As for frontend, use JavaScript to establish a SSE connection:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Message Broadcast</title>
    <script>
        function sendMessage() {
            const inputContent = document.getElementById('messageInput').value;
            const data = {
                broadcast: inputContent
            };
            if (!inputContent) return;
            fetch('/api/contest/admin/broadcast', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: Object.keys(data).map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key])).join('&')
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        }
        source = new EventSource('/api/contest/sse');
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
            alert(event.data);
        }
        source.onerror = function(event) {
            console.error('SSE connection error: ', event);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Message Broadcast Tool</h1>
    <p>Enter your message:</p>
    <input type="text" id="messageInput" placeholder="Type your message here...">
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
</body>
</html>

And nginx as a reverse proxy server:

#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            client_max_body_size 1G;
        }

        location /api {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            client_max_body_size 1G;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}

However, messages can not be sent instantly to the client. It was observed from logs that the client had successfully connected to the server URI /api/contest/sse , the server had received broadcast message from /api/contest/admin/broadcast and had sent the received message to client, but the client didn't receive that message.
2024-09-14T21:47:10.092+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 21.0.4 with PID 16020 (C:\develop\demo\target\classes started by gengy in C:\develop\demo)
2024-09-14T21:47:10.095+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-09-14T21:47:10.683+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-09-14T21:47:10.693+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-09-14T21:47:10.694+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.28]
2024-09-14T21:47:10.723+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-09-14T21:47:10.723+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 571 ms
2024-09-14T21:47:10.956+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-09-14T21:47:10.962+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.083 seconds (process running for 1.418)
2024-09-14T21:47:12.667+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-09-14T21:47:12.668+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-09-14T21:47:12.668+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
2024-09-14T21:47:12.688+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.demo.SseController           : (Unknown) connected to SSE, session: (Unknown)-2e96934e-8a86-4267-bbbd-48270698a79b
2024-09-14T21:47:22.963+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-2] com.example.demo.SseBroadcaster          : Message has been sent to (Unknown)-2e96934e-8a86-4267-bbbd-48270698a79b
2024-09-14T21:47:22.963+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-2] com.example.demo.SseController           : Published a broadcast: 5678

If I terminated the spring boot application, client would received the message and then close the connection. Another several lines of logs are printed:
2024-09-14T21:47:34.371+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-3] com.example.demo.SseController           : (Unknown) disconnected from SSE, session: (Unknown)-2e96934e-8a86-4267-bbbd-48270698a79b
2024-09-14T21:47:34.382+08:00  WARN 16020 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Ignoring exception, response committed already: org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestTimeoutException
2024-09-14T21:47:34.382+08:00  WARN 16020 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestTimeoutException]
2024-09-14T21:47:34.382+08:00  INFO 16020 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-3] com.example.demo.SseController           : (Unknown) disconnected from SSE, session: (Unknown)-2e96934e-8a86-4267-bbbd-48270698a79b

In short, client will never receive the message until I close the backend spring boot application.
If I use caddy as a reverse proxy server instead, the above problem disappears! So, it is believed that there are some mistakes in my nginx configuration. This problem is unrelated to the spring framework and javascript, just a problem with nginx.

this has been raised as an issue in Spring and the problem is not on the server side. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/33541 This question description is incomplete as nginx is also involved and might have a role here.
